Hoping implement color picker in a datagrid view. Code below launches the CP when the button in the DGV cell is clicked currentcell returns nothing
The currentcell in the code below returns 'nothing. Please help.
Private Sub dgvDMs_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvDMs.CellContentClick
Dim senderGrid = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
 If TypeOf senderGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewButtonColumn AndAlso
 e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
     If dgvDMs.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "ColorColumn" Then
         Dim dlg As ColorDialog = New ColorDialog()
         Dim currentCell As ColorPickerCell = TryCast(dgvDMs(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex), ColorPickerCell)


         If dlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

             If currentCell IsNot Nothing Then
                 currentCell.Color = dlg.Color
                 dgvDMs.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Style.BackColor = dlg.Color
                 Me.Invalidate()
             End If
         End If
     End If
 End If

End Sub
Colorpicker class
Public Class ColorPickerCell
Inherits DataGridViewButtonCell
Const phi As Single = 1.618F
Private colorValue As Color

Public Property Color As Color
    Get
        Return colorValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Color)
        colorValue = value
        Me.Value = value.ToArgb().ToString()
    End Set
End Property
Protected Overrides Sub Paint(graphics As Graphics, clipBounds As Rectangle,
 cellBounds As Rectangle, rowIndex As Integer, cellState As DataGridViewElementStates,
 value As Object, formattedValue As Object, errorText As String,
 cellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle, advancedBorderStyle As DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle,
 paintParts As DataGridViewPaintParts)

    'CDF: draw the button
    MyBase.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value,
    formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts)

    'CDF: draw a purty rectangle over the button
    Using darkPen As New Pen(SystemColors.ControlDark)
        Dim rc As New Rectangle(cellBounds.X + 8, cellBounds.Y + 3,
            cellBounds.Width - CInt(cellBounds.Width * phi / 8),
            cellBounds.Height - CInt(cellBounds.Height * phi / 4))

        graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(
            Integer.Parse(formattedValue.ToString()))), rc)
        graphics.DrawRectangle(darkPen, rc)
    End Using
End Sub

End Class
I have tried using an event handler to replace the cellcontent click event
I have tried the cell clickevent

What is the relation between the DataGridViewButtonColumn and your custom ColorPickerCell? Did you set the CellTemplate at some point? If so, show that, too

If you want to see your custom Column in the Columns' selector of a DataGridView, derive a class object from DataGridViewColumn and a class object from DataGridViewButtonColumn (if you want to use a Button as the default content of the Cell), then, in the Constructor of your custom Column, set its CellTemplate to a new instance of your Custom DataGridViewButtonColumn. That's all -- Here's an example of a custom Column with a custom Cell that's shown in the DataGridView Designer

Public Class DataGridViewColorPickerColumn
Inherits DataGridViewColumn

Public Sub New()
    CellTemplate = New DataGridViewColorPickerCell()
End Sub

End Class

Well, you're welcome, though it's not clear whether you got it working. Remember to override the Clone() method of your custom Cell, it's kind of mandatory
